# When installing cms-form-builder composer fails with Failed to generate package-lock.json

Tags: orocommerce

I'm new to Orocommerce, symfony, and composer.
I just installing a clean version of Orocommerce (AWS image) and trying to install cms-form-builder using composer.

when I run
php bin/composer require b2bcodext/cms-form-builder

I get the following error.

```
Updating the "config/parameters.yml" file
> Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::setPermissions
> Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::updateAssets
npm install --no-audit --save-exact --no-optional --loglevel error
sh: line 0: exec: npm: not found
Script Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::updateAssets handling the update-assets event terminated with an exception
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
In ScriptHandler.php line 149:
  Failed to generate package-lock.json
```

Not sure what this means - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> npm: not found

It says, the application cannot find NPM to install JavaScript dependencies.

If you haven't installed NPM yet, just follow the official guide to do that:
https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Alternatively, if it's already installed, but the application doesn't know where it is, you can provide the path to the NPM explicitly with the application configuration option: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/bundles/platform/AssetBundle/#configuration

Comment: Thank you very much, NPM was installed and the application was able to find it but there was a problem with one of its internal paths.

Comment: Once that ran I tried the next step which was to update oro platform : php bin/console oro:platform:update --env=prod --force-debug --force  which worked fine for dev but for prod it throws an error :   > Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\RefreshExtendCacheMigration


    In MappingException.php line 23:

  The class 'B2bCode\Bundle\CmsFormBundle\Entity\CmsFieldResponse' was not fo

      und in the chain configured namespaces Oro\Bundle\ScopeBundle\Entity, Or...
 Does that mean anything to you? and if it does what manual should I be reading?

Comment: There is no need to rerun it in dev and prod environments. One is enough. For another environment you just have to clear the cache, like `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: worked perfectly - thanks! is there a how to or an idiots guide for all of this - I've seen all these commands mentioned in various documents but nothing that actually explains what they do and why / when you would need to run them.

Comment: Cache per environment is a pure Symfony feature. At the same time, a database is the same, so to avoid inconsistency between cache and the application state, when you switch an environment, it's always required to clear the cache. This information is well covered in the first part of a free developer training: https://academy.oroinc.com/training/. It's the best place to start.

Comment: Excellent training - would have saved me loads of time if I found this earlier! Thanks